Functions not being listed after Azure deploy from GitHub
We were requested to migrate a company project from Azure DevOps to GitHub. We had several services, some being web apps, others Azure Functions. We migrated the web apps with no problem, yet for the Azure Functions we encounter the following problem no matter what we try: the pipeline is executed successfully, the app is running, yet the functions disappear from under the function app in the Azure portal, after the deploy from GitHub.
We work with .NET 8. I checked for the runtimes to match, and everything (project, function app in Azure portal, the environment in the workflow) is set to .NET 8 isolated.
I tried doing a dummy function app and connecting it to GitHub from the development center, just like I did with the company project and it worked, the functions are listed in the portal with no issue. I checked for the environment variables and configurations to match, but the problem does not reside here. The only change I did to the auto-generated workflows is the path to the function app root folder, for both the dummy project and the company one. The workflow looks like this:
name: Build and deploy dotnet core app to Azure Function App - test-function-gs-ita

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

env:
  AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH: './GS-App/GS-App/' # set this to the path to your web app project, defaults to the repository root
  DOTNET_VERSION: '8.0.x' # set this to the dotnet version to use

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
      - name: 'Checkout GitHub Action'
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Setup DotNet ${{ env.DOTNET_VERSION }} Environment
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
        with:
          dotnet-version: ${{ env.DOTNET_VERSION }}

      - name: 'Resolve Project Dependencies Using Dotnet'
        shell: pwsh
        run: |
          pushd './${{ env.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}'
          dotnet build --configuration Release --output ./output
          popd
      - name: 'Run Azure Functions Action'
        uses: Azure/functions-action@v1
        id: fa
        with:
          app-name: 'test-function-gs'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          package: '${{ env.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}/output'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE }}

I checked the app's contents in Kudu and it seems fine. My only concern is that MAYBE the company app is under my organization in GitHub, while the dummy application is directly under my account. I can't think of any other difference between the two. Both of them have basic authentication enabled.
I also tried manually deploying the function app from Visual Studio and the functions are back up, meaning that there's no code error not allowing the function to start or working properly.
Can anyone guide me on where to look or investigate further, on why the functions are not listed? Or maybe someone else already had this happen and there's a solution I have not found yet. If anything else is needed, please let me know and I'll update the question with the required information.
Edit: Here's the folder structure. The solution file is in the root folder of the project, while I am interested in deploying the function apps (App1-App6) under ./src/Providers/Provider2:

./src/Providers/Provider2/App1
./src/Providers/Provider2/App2
./src/Providers/Provider2/App3
./src/Providers/Provider2/App4
./src/Providers/Provider2/App5
./src/Providers/Provider2/App6



Can you share your function code?

@VivekVaibhavShandilya Unfortunately I cannot, since it is company code. I updated my question and I also stated that I tried manually publishing the function app from Visual Studio, and it works (the functions are listed in the Azure portal), so it should not be a code-related issue. It also works if I deploy it from Azure DevOps, so this problem should not be caused by code issues.

Can you share the folder structure of your repo from root directory?

When deploying functions in dotnet function app using GitHub Actions, Make sure to mention the path of the .sln file or .csproj file in
AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH in .yml file.
I tried both method and it worked for me.
My repo directory structure :

Below given .yml file worked for me.
name: Build and deploy dotnet core app to Azure Function App - gitfunc1july

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

env:
  AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH: '.' OR './GitHubfunc'     # for '.sln' file and '.csproj' file respectively
  DOTNET_VERSION: '8.0.x' # set this to the dotnet version to use

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    
    steps:
      - name: 'Checkout GitHub Action'
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Setup DotNet ${{ env.DOTNET_VERSION }} Environment
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
        with:
          dotnet-version: ${{ env.DOTNET_VERSION }}

      - name: 'Resolve Project Dependencies Using Dotnet'
        shell: pwsh
        run: |
          pushd './${{ env.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}'
          dotnet build --configuration Release --output ./output
          popd
      
      - name: 'Run Azure Functions Action'
        uses: Azure/functions-action@v1
        id: fa
        with:
          app-name: 'gitfunc1july'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          package: '${{ env.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}/output'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_7AA971xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx }}

OUTPUT:




Thank you for the effort! You may be right and I might need to set the path to the solution, not to the function app root folder. However, there is a problem: I have multiple function apps and the solution file is in a folder above the function apps folders. I will try setting the path to the solution file instead of the function app root folder and see what happens. Will come back with an update.

The only problem with setting the path to the solution is that I need to build different function apps under the solution and deploy them to separate function apps in Azure. I edited my question with a project folder structure. I tried setting different paths to different function apps (both for build and output directories), yet my function apps still disappear once the deployment is finished.

@GabrielStancu are there .csproj file in each of the App folder?

Yes, there's a .csproj file in each of the 6 App folders.

@GabrielStancu try passing the ./src/Providers/Provider2/App1 path in the AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH value.

I tried, but the functions get deleted after deployment.

if you deploy new function to Function app it clears any previous functions available in that function app and deploys a new function. if you want multiple function in your function app the your function should be in single directory and create .cs file of each function in the same app.

I am not sure I understood. I have multiple function apps, each one under one of the App folders. I want to have them all deployed, and each function app (each App folder) should go to a different function app in Azure.
